# Index causes and Error in Updating Row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Why does Index causes an error in MySQL Update row? Removing it makes the Query work.

The error is

> MySQLi failed to query: UPDATE quests SET id = '1', FactionID = '2', ReqReputation = '2', ReqClassID = '3', ReqClassPoints = '2', Name = '2', Description = '2', EndText = '2', Experience = '2', GExperience = '2', Copper = '2', Silver = '2', Gold = '2', Coins = '2', Reputation = '2', ClassPoints = '2', RewardType = 'S', Level = '2', Upgrade = '1', Once = '1', Slot = '2', Value = '2', Field = '2', Index = '2', Badges = '3', Guild = '1', GiveMembership = '0', War = '1' WHERE id = 1 - December 20, 2016, 1:58 am

```
            $id = $_POST["Id"];
            $FactionID = $_POST["Faction"];
            $ReqReputation =  $_POST["RequiredReputation"];
            $ReqClassID =  $_POST["Class"];
            $ReqClassPoints =  $_POST["ReqClassRank"];
            $Name = $_POST["Name"];
            $Description =  $_POST["Description"];
            $EndText =  $_POST["EndText"];
            $Experience =  $_POST["Experience"];
            $GExperience =  $_POST["GuildExperience"];
            $Copper =  $_POST["Copper"];
            $Silver =  $_POST["Silver"];
            $Gold =  $_POST["Gold"];
            $Coins =  $_POST["Diamond"];
            $Reputation =  $_POST["Reputation"];
            $ClassPoints =  $_POST["ClassPoints"];
            $RewardType =  $_POST["RewardType"];
            $Level =  $_POST["Level"];
            $Upgrade =  $_POST["Upgrade"];
            $Once =  $_POST["Once"];
            $Slot =  $_POST["Slot"];
            $Value =  $_POST["Value"];
            $Field =  $_POST["Field"];
            $QIndex =  $_POST["Index"];
            $Badges =  $_POST["Badges"];
            $Guild =  $_POST["Guild"];
            $GiveMembership =  $_POST["GiveMembership"];
            $War =  $_POST["War"];

            $MYSQL_QUERY = $content->DBase('Query', array( 0 => "UPDATE quests SET id = '$id', FactionID = '$FactionID', ReqReputation = '$ReqReputation', ReqClassID = '$ReqClassID', ReqClassPoints = '$ReqClassPoints', Name = '$Name', Description = '$Description', EndText = '$EndText', Experience = '$Experience', GExperience = '$GExperience', Copper = '$Copper', Silver = '$Silver', Gold = '$Gold', Coins = '$Coins', Reputation = '$Reputation', ClassPoints = '$ClassPoints', RewardType = '$RewardType', Level = '$Level', Upgrade = '$Upgrade', Once = '$Once', Slot = '$Slot', Value = '$Value', Field = '$Field', Index = '$Index', Badges = '$Badges', Guild = '$Guild', GiveMembership = '$GiveMembership', War = '$War' WHERE id = $id"));
```

Function DBase

```
/** MYSQL IMPROVED EXTENSION (PARENT CLASS) **/
public function DBase($type, $params = array()) {
    if (!$this->SITE->CMS->Connection)
        SystemExit('No available MySQLi connection', __LINE__, __FILE__);

    switch (strtoupper($type)) {
        case 'QUERY':
            if ($Query = parent::query($params[0])) {
                $this->SITE->CMS->TotalQuery++;
                return $Query;
            } else
                SystemExit('MySQLi failed to query: ' . $params[0], __LINE__, __FILE__);
            break;
        case 'PREPARE':
            if ($Query = parent::prepare($params[0])) {
                $this->SITE->CMS->TotalQuery++;
                return $Query;
            } else
                SystemExit('MySQLi failed to prepare: ' . $params[0], __LINE__, __FILE__);
            break;
        case 'ESCAPESTRING':                
            if ($Escape = parent::real_escape_string($params[0]))
                return $Escape;
            else
                SystemExit('MySQLi failed to escape: ' . $params[0], __LINE__, __FILE__);                
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the Table Quest
[image: TableQuest]

Comment: Stop posting table structure as image. Rather post it as text

Comment: I've flagged this as off topic because it doesn't contain a [mcve]. Please edit the question to reduce the example code to the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong variable for index. You define it above as $QIndex but then refer to it as $Index on the last line. Try the following:

```
            $id = $_POST["Id"];
            $FactionID = $_POST["Faction"];
            $ReqReputation =  $_POST["RequiredReputation"];
            $ReqClassID =  $_POST["Class"];
            $ReqClassPoints =  $_POST["ReqClassRank"];
            $Name = $_POST["Name"];
            $Description =  $_POST["Description"];
            $EndText =  $_POST["EndText"];
            $Experience =  $_POST["Experience"];
            $GExperience =  $_POST["GuildExperience"];
            $Copper =  $_POST["Copper"];
            $Silver =  $_POST["Silver"];
            $Gold =  $_POST["Gold"];
            $Coins =  $_POST["Diamond"];
            $Reputation =  $_POST["Reputation"];
            $ClassPoints =  $_POST["ClassPoints"];
            $RewardType =  $_POST["RewardType"];
            $Level =  $_POST["Level"];
            $Upgrade =  $_POST["Upgrade"];
            $Once =  $_POST["Once"];
            $Slot =  $_POST["Slot"];
            $Value =  $_POST["Value"];
            $Field =  $_POST["Field"];
            $QIndex =  $_POST["Index"];
            $Badges =  $_POST["Badges"];
            $Guild =  $_POST["Guild"];
            $GiveMembership =  $_POST["GiveMembership"];
            $War =  $_POST["War"];

            $MYSQL_QUERY = $content->DBase('Query', array( 0 => "UPDATE quests SET id = '$id', FactionID = '$FactionID', ReqReputation = '$ReqReputation', ReqClassID = '$ReqClassID', ReqClassPoints = '$ReqClassPoints', Name = '$Name', Description = '$Description', EndText = '$EndText', Experience = '$Experience', GExperience = '$GExperience', Copper = '$Copper', Silver = '$Silver', Gold = '$Gold', Coins = '$Coins', Reputation = '$Reputation', ClassPoints = '$ClassPoints', RewardType = '$RewardType', Level = '$Level', Upgrade = '$Upgrade', Once = '$Once', Slot = '$Slot', Value = '$Value', Field = '$Field', Index = '$QIndex', Badges = '$Badges', Guild = '$Guild', GiveMembership = '$GiveMembership', War = '$War' WHERE id = $id"));
```

Also see @Rahul 's comment too. Your: "WHERE id='$id'" seems to be passing the wrong value. An ID is most likely not that version of a date/time. if you want to use the current date + time you could us something like [NOW()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp) It gives you the current date and time down to the second.

Comment: I removed the Q in QIndex and its still not working.

Comment: Are you able to give an output of the quests table structure? It may be that you are trying to insert index into the wrong place in the table.

Comment: Renaming the Index to Index2 column works. Any idea why Index causes and error?

Comment: @NylzonRedulaII it is listed as a reserved word here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: that should be it. Thanks for helping.